# Bootstrap modal form empty spaces issues

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal

There appear to have empty spaces in front of the first row of the form, but wasn't able to identify what is in front of it, or what is actually causing this problem, the last 2 rows works fine but after adjustment of the web screen, it pushes the textbox out of the form, any help or advice is strongly appreciated.

```css
.input-lgchan {
  height: 40px;
  width: 32rem;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.3333333;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

#output_image {
  border-style: solid;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.inputfile {
  width: 0.1px;
  height: 0.1px;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}

.label {
  opacity: 0;
}

.inputfile+label {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2px 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
}

.inputfile:focus+label,
.inputfile+label:hover {}

.inputfile+label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.iconplus {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg">
            Instagram Like
        </button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl  modal-dialog-right" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header ">
        <h2 style="font-family: Lato; font-size:29pt; font-weight:bold;" class="modal-title " id="exampleModalLongTitle">Instagram</h2>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body form-horizontal">
        <form class="form-horizontal" id="step2">
          <img id="output_image" height=270px width=270px>
          <input class="inputfile" type="file" id="getFile" accept="image/*" onchange="preview_image(event)">
          <label for="getFile" <i class="fa fa-plus-circle iconplus" style="position:relative; top:23.1rem; right:3.45rem;"></i> </label>



          <div class="form-group row align-items-center justify-content-center">
            <label style="font-family:Lato; font-size:20pt; font-weight:normal;" for="name" class="col-sm-4 control-label col text-left">Staff ID:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-5 ">
              <input id="name" class="form-control input-lg row align-items-left justify-content-left" style="margin-right:6.8rem;" type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Email Address" />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group row align-items-center justify-content-center">
            <label style="font-family:Lato; font-size:20pt; font-weight:normal;" for="name" class="col-sm-4 control-label col text-left">Email:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-5 ">
              <input id="name" class="form-control input-lg row align-items-left justify-content-left" type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Email Address" />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group row align-items-center justify-content-center">
            <label style="font-family:Lato; font-size:20pt; font-weight:normal;" for="name" class="col-sm-4 control-label col text-left">Email:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-5 ">
              <input id="name" class="form-control input-lg row align-items-left justify-content-left" type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Email Address" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>


      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

</body>
```